# Continuous Integration for Swing UI Testing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, continuous-integration

I have done automated UI testing before on a major WPF project and it worked very well.

I'm now moving onto a Java Swing project, and have been doing some research on Swing UI testing. Primarily I'm looking for a library, with the following:

1. Integration into Maven and CI server
2. Mainstream / Popular - So we don't have to change frameworks, or
   rewrite our tests when that framework become obselete and is not
   supported.
3. Ease of writing tests
4. Re-use of tests

From my research I have found the following Frameworks, and was wondering if people had experience in them to give me some pros/cons ?

1. WindowsTester
2. Jubula
3. FEST
4. Jemmy

I know there have been similar questions asked before on stackoverflow, however frameworks change so rapidly with new revisions, or becoming obselete.

Comment: oh, and they must be free-to-use of course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Maveryx](http://www.maveryx.com). It is a free and open source test automation framework.

Answer (score 0):

For the GUI test I use a *no framework and no mock* solution - only swing, and swingx, because I already use swingx, and of course my code.

I use MVC with some Presenter flavour (or the inverse). To build the GUI with ligth view level and presenter stuff is very usefull for GUI test.

Answer (score 0):

Using TAP-Plugin, [ReTest](https://www.retest.de/en/) integrates directly into Jenkins. It is a relatively new tool with an innovative approach to functional regression testing, combined with ai-based monkey testing.

It is about to become open source as well.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of the company behind ReTest.